# How to work out percentages for every answer in a dataset and display percentage in brackets

Tags: r

I would like to know how to work out the percentage for each answer in a dataset and then display the percentage in brackets sides it.What code can I write to achieve this?

This is the dataset I am working with

```
           A    B     C      D
50% 26.73194  5.5 21.50  9.150
5%  18.91642  1.6  4.55  7.645
95% 31.14233 21.3 56.30 10.570
```

I would like to calculate the percentage for all the figures in the dataset, with the number 39938 equating to 100%.

I would then like to display the percentage in brackets next to each figure.

The dataset I would like to achieve looks like this:

```
            A            B           C             D 
50% 26.73194(0.066)  5.5(0.014) 21.50(0.054)  9.150(0.002) 
5%  18.91642(0.047)  1.6(0.004)  4.55(0.001)  7.645(0.017) 
95% 31.14233(0.77)   21.3(0.054) 56.30(0.14) 10.570(0.025)
```

Comment: How does 1.63 amount to 54%

Comment: Related question - how does NA equal 20.50?  You should do a bit of quality checks on your examples if you want good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clearly stated, but I think you want this:

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) {paste0(x,"(",round(x/3,2),")")})
```

which results in:

```
> df1
           A       B
1 1.63(0.54)    6(2)
2 20.5(6.83) 1(0.33)
3      18(6) 5(1.67)
4  26.7(8.9)   24(8)
```

The division by three is due to the fact that the value of 300 is supposed to correspond to 100% according to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(~paste0(.x, '(', round(.x * 100 / sum(.x)), ')'))
```

Comment: What package contains mutate_all as I can't find it in R

Comment: `dplyr`. Sry for not including it.

Comment: when I try this, i receive the error message :Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"

Comment: This doesn't produce the same output as shown in the question. OP should better clarify what they actually want to do.

Comment: @M.G Transform yours data frame to tibble with as_tibble() function.

Comment: If the OP is getting that error, it's because they've got a matrix. It should work on a data frame regardless of whether it's a tibble or not, but it won't work on a matrix. The fact that it's a matrix wasn't included in the question though, so that's not on you to have known or not

Answer (score 0):

From another user's answer, then the expected output can be got using:

```
as.data.frame(purrr::map(df,function(x) paste0(x,"(",round(x/3,2),")")))


        A       B
1 1.63(0.54)    6(2)
2 20.5(6.83) 1(0.33)
3      18(6) 5(1.67)
4  26.7(8.9)   24(8)
```

The original question was unclear.

**ORIGINAL**

The expected output and the logic pathway are unclear. Here's an attempt:

```
 Vals<-colSums(df)#I actually think nrow(df) is better
Values<-as.vector(Vals)
    as.data.frame(purrr::map2(df,Values,function(x,y)  paste0(x,"(",round(x*100/y,2),")")))
```

This gives: This uses column sums to get the percentages.

```
        A         B
1  1.63(2.44)  6(16.67)
2 20.5(30.67)   1(2.78)
3   18(26.93)  5(13.89)
4 26.7(39.95) 24(66.67)
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't give the desired outcome. I have altered my original post, how can I change the code to get my desired outcome